# MySQL trigger DELETE old rows AFTER INSERT

Tags: mysql, triggers, timestamp, sql-delete

Whats wrong with this MySQL trigger? After insert I'm trying to delete rows older than 1 month. This trigger only removes the last inserted row.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `users_logins_delete_olds` 
AFTER INSERT ON `users_logins` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM users_logins WHERE user_id = new.user_id AND timestamp < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH);
END
```

Comment: What is the data type of `timestamp`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff It's `DATETIME` like 0000-00-00 00:00:00.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't delete the rows from the same table on which you implement the trigger.
Because on insert mysql locks the table and can't delete the rows because delete needs locking so its a deadlock sitution, that's why mysql would not allow this.

Comment: I also tried to create an event, but even that didn't work. @AmanAggarwal

Comment: its better to create a small procedure and run it via code when you insert the data in table..

Comment: So you can't use `DELETE` in MySQL events?

Answer (score 0):

try DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)

Comment: I changed `timestamp < (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` to `timestamp < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 MONTH)` and no effect.